# mysql count group by order by optimization

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table to store `tag name` for `posts`

```
table: tagname
tags                    |  pid
festival                | 10034
New York Fashion Week   | 10034
festival                | 10035
car                     | 10036
...
```

The table now has already 590,000 records. Now I want to get the first 10 most popular tags from this table.

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(*) as Num FROM tagname
GROUP BY tags
ORDER BY Num DESC
```

This will cost 23.88 seconds. return `358 kinds of tags`

```
tags       |  Num
festival   |  7201
art        |  6988
gift       |  6755
...
```

How to optimization this query, even in `my.cnf`? I tried to add index for tags, it seems with no effect.

EDIT: 
`EXPLAIN SELECT tags, COUNT(tags) as Num  FROM`tagname`GROUP BY tags  order by Num DESC`

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      tagname ALL     NULL    NULL     NULL    NULL   597649  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: what datatype your defined for column tag?

Comment: @silly, tags varchar(80), pid int(8)

Comment: i think the best solution will be a tag table for your unique tag strings.... in the tag_name table you can store just the id to the new table...

Comment: @cj333: it does not say `Using index` so either you have not defined an index (as suggested by juergen) or defined incorrectly (`tags(10) ASC` means only first 10 characters are indexed). You might be able to eliminate `Using temporary` by increasing memory allocated to MySQL.

Comment: @Salman is right. Drop that `tags(10)` index and make one on the full length of `tags`:  `ALTER TABLE tagname ADD INDEX tags_index (tags) ;`

Comment: The Explain will then show: `Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index to your `tags` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `tagname` 
ADD INDEX `tags_index` (`tags` ASC) ;
```

### EDIT:

Try creating a  second index

```
CREATE INDEX tags_pid_index ON tagname (tags, pid);
```

Then modify your query to:

```
SELECT tags, COUNT(pid) as Num 
FROM tagname
GROUP BY tags
ORDER BY Num DESC
```

Comment: INDEX with no effect... still need 20+ seconds.

Comment: @cj333: Then try `COUNT(tags)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE `tagname` ADD INDEX `tags_index` (`tags`(10) ASC)`, `SELECT tags, COUNT(tags) as Num FROM tagname GROUP BY tags ORDER BY Num DESC`, 21.16s.

Comment: Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN <your query>` and see if it says `using temporary`?

Comment: @cj333: Add the new Explain of the query, after the index was added.

Comment: @ypercube, this is the explain after the index was added. I see `table Structure` in `phpmyadmin` there has an index in `Indexes: tags_index INDEX 358 tags 10`.

Comment: @juergen d, not very clear, why `COUNT(pid)`? `pid` is post id, but now I want to get the first 10 most popular tags.

Comment: @cj333: If you have an index that holds both: tagname and pid then the query does not need to create a temporary table to count the records because it can do it with the index on pid and tagname. Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
    SELECT tags, COUNT(*) as Num FROM tagname
    GROUP BY tags HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY Num DESC LIMIT 10
```

The trick can be: If you know the minimum popularity number, you can change the number in COUNT(*)  > x

Thanks

Comment: Recently, I faced the same kind of problem. A solution may be to omit LIMIT option in SQL query. Rather sort it out in script level. This information may help you also. That way my script runs 5 times faster.